# Можно ли использовать сокеты не в локальной сети?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, ip, localhost

Использую модуль socket, когда в команде socket.connect() использую локальный ip, то все работает но мой комп должен быть в одной сети с другим, чтобы все работало. Есть ли способ подключаться к другим машинам, которые находятся в других сетях? Вот код клиента, если нужен.

````
#client
import socket

sock =  socket.socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.1.172', 9090))
sock.send("Conection confirmed!".encode())
print("CONFIRMED")

while True:

    a=input("CLIENT: ")


    a=a.encode()
    sock.send(a)



sock.close()```
````

Comment: Нужно пробросить порт и открыть фаервол

Answer (score 2):

Да можно конечно. Кто мешает?

Вот примерчик.

```py
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('example.com', 80))
    s.sendall(b"HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nAccept: text/html\r\n\r\n")
    r = s.recv(1000)

print(r)
```